# XML read with conditions within xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

i have following XML code. i want to if lang = English then EnglishCover.jpf will show else hindi.

```
<languages>
<lang name="English"></lang>
<lang name="Hindi"></lang>
</languages>
<pagesList>
<page bg="EnglishCover.jpg"/> 
<page bg="HindiCover.jpg"/> 
</pageList>
```

Can we do this within XML only. Can we add if else conditions within same code.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. XML does not have that capability. You will need to write it into whatever software processes the XML.